# how to run multiple commands at once on multiple server by running and exiting automaticaly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh

i have a problem in running commands in sequence on terminal, see below scenario---

```
ssh ubuntu@123.234.234.321 (get root access)
ssh 243.43.2.1 (to connect a system)
sudo killall python (killing python on ssh 243.43.2.1)
exit (exiting 243.43.2.1)
ssh 567.563.65.3 (to connect a another system)
sudo killall python (killing python on ssh 567.563.65.3)
exit  (exiting 567.563.65.3)
exit (exiting root)
```

The problem when i paste whole sequence of commands on terminal it doesn't continue after first exit command.

Is there any way to do it?? thank you.

Comment: Are you actually adding the stuff in brackets too? Don't copy and paste. Understand what you're doing. There's a few gotchas here, like that sshing, then sshing again...

Answer (score 2):

For linux, the best possible option is to make a script file (also called a shell script) and run it instead of pasting all the commands on the terminal. This will execute all of your commands step by step. If you are working on Windows then you can achieve the same functionality by building a batch or command file.

For more info on shell scripting and batch files you can refer these links:

- [Shell scripts](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-shell-scripting-lessons/)
- [Batch files](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm)

Comment: External links should be avoided here because they may break. On the other hand pasting complete tutorials is an overkill. I think you may improve your answer by giving an example of a script that solves OP's problem. Nevertheless the first part of your answer will point in a right direction even if the links break, even without examples. That's why you get +1 from me.